# Luggage carrier for fatbike

Tags: rack, cargo, fatbike

I need a bicycle luggage carrier (rack) for my Scott Big Ed fat bike, but it is not easy to find one that fits. And it looks like it is not possible to add front rack since the bike has front suspension.

Can you recommend a baggage carrier solutions for the fat bike?

Comment: Does a back pack suit your need ?  Or a frame bag might be a solution.

Answer (score 3):

Old Man Mountain [sells a kit](http://www.oldmanmountain.com/Merchant2/merchant.mvc?Screen=CTGY&Store_Code=O&Category_Code=front-3-5_fat_disc_15mm-through_bluto) (PH-SH-F-THRU-BLUTO) for mounting their Phat Wide Sherpa Rack on the front with a RockShox Bluto fork (which your bike has).

To quote the page:

> Phat Sherpa Front with 15mm Thru Axle (For Rockshox Bluto). Comes with Robert Axle Project replacement thru axle and all other parts needed for installation. Part Numbers included in this compilation: PH-W, FK-5F15, AX-15BL, QRXLR170, EX6, CL1.5

Alternatively, you can look at their [selection of rear racks](http://www.oldmanmountain.com/category/rear-fat.html).